# c++ code refactoring using function objects

Tags: c++, functor

I have some functionality that returns a value based on values that are set once at start up (in constructor). As these conditional value are only set once, I dont want to be checking them all the time.
Is there a way to do the if-check only once and then dont do it again and again using function objects or some other mechanism?

```
class MyValue {
    bool myVal; //set only once in the constructor
    int myval1; //often updates
    int myval2; //often updates


    myValue(bool val, int val1, int val2)
    {
        myVal = val; // only place where myVal is set

        // this value changes often in other functions not shown here
        myval1 = val1;

        // this value changes often in other functions not shown here
        myval2 = val2;
    }

    int GetMyValue() //often called
    {
        if(myval)    /* Is there a way I dont have to do an if check here? 
                        and simply write a return statement? */
            return myval1;

        return myval2;
    }    
};
```

Comment: can you perhaps use just a single value `int myval` and set it using `myval = val ? val1 : val2;` in the constructor?

Comment: "set once at start-up" Are they known at compile-time? Related: Can you use C++11?

Comment: Don't engage in premature optimizations. Branch prediction makes wonders. That being said, you can have a pointer to one or another, set it at construction time and than derefrence for return.

Comment: yes I can use c++11. the value is not known at compile time as it is based on userinput. both myval1 and myval2 need to be stored separately as they have other uses.

Comment: Ok, that info was originally missing. You can set a pointer to the int you are interested in depending on the `bool` param and have `GetMyValue` return `*ptrToCorrectMyVal`

Comment: If it's only set once, during construction, can it be `const`?

Comment: mmm..probably not because the value is based on user input and there is a rare situation where the myval can be changed but its much much less in frequency with which GetMyVal() is called

Comment: If `myval` can ever change during the course of your program, then your question implies that you intend on writing a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pointer:

```
class MyValue
{
   int* myVal;
   int myval1; //often updates
   int myval2; //often updates

  myValue(bool val, int val1, int val2)
  {
     if (val) { 
         myVal = &myval1; 
     } else { 
         myVal = &myval2 
     }
     myval1 = val1;
     myval2 = val2;
  }

  int GetMyValue() //often called
  {
     return *myval;
  }

};
```

(or even better a reference as in Rabbid76 answer)

Comment: I will prefer not to introduce a new global variable. can function objects help in this situation?

Comment: I think you would still need a variable to store the function object instance

Comment: i am ok with storing function object instance.

Comment: @bsobaid: How is storing a function object instance any better than storing an `int*`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a member which is either a reference to `myval1` or to `myval2`, the referenc has to be initialized once in the constructor:

```
class MyValue
{
    bool myVal; //set only once in the constructor
    int myval1; //often updates
    int myval2; //often updates
    int &valref;

public:
    MyValue( bool val, int val1, int val2 )
        : myVal( val )
        , myval1( val1 )
        , myval2( val2 )
        , valref( val ? myval1 : myval2 )
    {}

    int GetMyVal() { return valref; }
};
```